# Wrapping in Clojure

Tags: clojure, macros

Sometimes I've trouble to wrap function or macros in Clojure.

For example [Clojure Mongo](http://clojuremongodb.info/) offers a DSL to query collections: [with-collection](http://reference.clojuremongodb.info/monger.query.html#var-with-collection), which is a macro.

One way to use it is shown below:

```
(with-collection db coll
    (find {})
    (sort (array-map :score -1 :name 1)))
```

I'd like to create a function that receives sort function and calls with-collection.

```
(defn find [sort]
    (with-collection my-db my-coll
       (find {})
       sort
)
```

If I try to invoke that function I get the following error: ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn

```
(find (sort (array-map :score -1 :name 1))
```

I guess it's because sort is being evaluated and with-collection expects a function.

If I try to quote I get the following error: ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistentList cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn

```
(find (quote sort (array-map :score -1 :name 1)))
```

If I try to pass an anonymous function I get the following error: ArityException Wrong number of args (1) passed to: main/eval139628/fn--139629

```
(find #(sort (array-map :score -1 :name 1))
```

Is it possible to wrap this kind of macro using functions? Thanks.

Comment: Your anonymous functions takes no arguments. Try  `#(sort % (array-map :score -1 :name 1))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the thing is the `with-collection` macro expands to a `->`, so your function should have the coll as the first parameter. Also you shadow the monger `find` function with your `find function. Probably you should do something like this:

```
(defn my-find [sort]
  (with-collection my-db my-coll
    (find {})
    sort)
```

and call it like this:

```
(my-find #(sort % (array-map :score -1 :name 1))
```